# echo "x" if entry not found in table?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

can someone please tell me what type of statement i would use when i have a mysql query to fetch user photos from my table and i want it so that if a user has no photos or the entry doesnt exist in the table it should echo out something else?

Im new to php and mysql so if someone can give me an example this will really help. thank you.

My query that fetches the users photos is below, theres an if logged in to show larger images and a if logged out to not have links to larger images. please note i have tried an else statement but this just causes my else echoed text to show with users photos.

```
    <?php
        $get_photos_set = get_photos();
        while ($photos = mysql_fetch_array($get_photos_set)) {
            if (logged_in()) {
              echo "<li><a href=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/{$photos['file_name']}\" rel=\"prettyPhoto[pp_gal]\"><img src=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/thumb_{$photos['file_name']}\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
            } else {
              echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/thumb_{$photos['file_name']}\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

EDIT:

When i edit it to this, i still get nothing being echoed if the result = false:

```
                          <?php
$get_photos_set = get_photos();
while ($photos = mysql_fetch_array($get_photos_set)) {
    if(!isset($get_photos_set) || $get_photos_set===false)
//Echo something else
echo "no results found";
else

//Do what you were normally doing
    if (logged_in()) {


echo
"<li><a href=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/{$photos['file_name']}\" rel=\"prettyPhoto[pp_gal]\"><img src=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/thumb_{$photos['file_name']}\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";
    }


    if (!logged_in()) {
echo
"<li><a href=\"login.php\"><img src=\"data/photos/{$photos['user_id']}/thumb_{$photos['file_name']}\" alt=\"{$profile[2]}'s Photos\"  /></a></li>";


 }


}




?>
```

Comment: @vivek, you've changed the OP's program structure with your edit, rather than just cleaning up line breaks. The fact that the OP branched `if (logged_in())` and then `if (!logged_in())` *rather than* the way you have (correctly) formatted it needs to be addressed from a pedagogical perspective. I would leave them.

Comment: what is the query `$get_photos_set`?

Comment: You really shouldn't use the deprecated mysql api - use mysqli or PDO instead!

Answer (score 3):

You can check the number of rows returned to see if photos were found:

```
$get_photos_set = get_photos();
if (mysql_num_rows($get_photos_set) > 0) {
  // do loop
} else {
  echo 'x';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this a couple of ways, however a simple method involves implementing a counter in to your loop. After, check the counter after the while loop is done and output anything you may want for an 'empty result'. e.g.

```
$results = 0;
$get_photos_set = get_photos();
while ($photos = mysql_fetch_array($get_photos_set)){
  // output
  $results++;
}
if ($results == 0){
  // no results output
}
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to work if i put an echo in under if ($results == 0){ its just blank.

Comment: Chances are your while is failing. Ideally you should be using something like `while (($photos = mysql_fetch_array($get_photos_set)) !== false){` (test against `false`) instead of relying on the assignment within the loop returning something truthy.